# How to create custom payment gateway in magento?

Tags: api, magento, payment-gateway, magento2, payment

The only things I need:

1. Get order id and customer id.
2. Create redirect url (this must be done on backend, url is signed with private hash)
3. Redirect user to this user
4. Upon success verify signature of redirect data and set order status
5. Upon failure verify signature of redirect data and set order status

Is there some simple module, which does these things so I can modify it for my needs?
This module should not use deprecated AbstractMethod, if possible.

I'm new to magento and documentation about payment gateway is too bloated. Plus it is hard to understant all these config pools and commands in configuration.

P.S. Magento 2 only with new payment gateway api.